# Evaluating expression at infinity

Tags: integration, limits, self-learning

How do I evaluate something like:

$$xe^{-(x-\theta)}\text{ from }x = \theta\text{ to }x=\infty?$$

This came up in an integration I tried to do, and I realize it's a very basic question. But I am confused on how to properly evaluate the expression at $\infty$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean integrating?

Comment: Nope, not integrating. I've already integrated the original function and it has come out to $xe^{-(x-\theta)}$. I just need to plug in $\infty$ as the upper bound and $\theta$ as the lower bound. But I don't know how to evaluate the expression at $\infty$.

Comment: I understand. Does my answer make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously when $x=\theta$ we get $$\theta e^{-(\theta - \theta)} = \theta \cdot e^0 = \theta \cdot 1 = \theta$$

For the other infinite case, you should know that the exponential grows faster than the linear function, so $e^{-(x-\theta)}$ goes to zero faster than $x$ goes to infinity, hence:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} xe^{-(x-\theta)} = 0$$

Comment: Great, thanks! Makes sense.

Comment: If the this post answered your question (considering other answers) than it is good habit to mark it as answered. Just click on the $\checkmark$ on the left.

Answer (score 0):

You take the limit, so:

$$  xe^{-(x-\theta)}\,\Big|_\theta^\infty=\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}xe^{-(x-\theta)}\right)-\theta e^{-(\theta-\theta)}=0-\theta=\theta.$$